# How to have multiple THREE.Texture instances backed by the same WebGL Texture

Tags: three.js

I may not have asked the correct question. My end goal is that I want to be able to use a texture in multiple places while having each texture's repeat and offset vary by usage.

My texture comes from a WebGLRenderTarget. I want to have two materials use the same texture, but each material gets its own offset and repeat.

Thanks

Comment: Keep a common `url` for your texture, and when you're setting the `offset` and `textureRepeat`, you can manually set that in the material (Apologies if I misinterpreted your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal textures, latest `three.js` versions support this use case. Meaning you can load a texture once, clone it via `Texture.clone()` and then use each texture instance with a different uv transformation. All textures will shared the same raw `WebGLTexture` object.

However, this workflow is not supported for render targets since the texture instance is tightly coupled to the instance of `WebGLRenderTarget` and its internal resources. Meaning you have to clone the entire render target, not just its texture property. However, cloned render targets don't share their framebuffers. So you end up with duplicate texture data.

This is a limitation of the engine and there is currently no way to workaround this (at least with built-in materials).

Comment: "there is currently no way to workaround this" *sad*. Thank you!